# 301 redirect nginx folder contents to subfolder

Tags: redirect, nginx

I've got a folder with a load of images in it...

/assets/images/

...and I've changed it to have two versions...

/assets/images/large
/assets/images/small

My logs are getting loads of 404s for the original folder structure so I want a redirect to stop this.

How can I redirect all requests for the original folder to look in the large folder? The filenames are the same. What I've tried so far also redirects everything it finds in the new folder structure and gets into a terrible mess.

TIA!

Comment: Your best bet is to use an alias for serving the static content. Please post your NGINX configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to hide the `/large/` folder from the clients, add this location:

```
location ~ /assets/images/([^/]*)$ {
  try_files /assets/images/large/$1 =404;
}
```

If you want your clients to "learn" about the `large` folder, use this:

```
location ~ /assets/images/([^/]*)$ {
  return 301 /assets/images/large/$1;
}
```

The HTTP status 301 means "Moved Permanently".

The regular expression allows anything but a `/`, so it effectively does not match `/assets/images/large/a.jpg`, which is what you want.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a bunch :)